# Pregunta acerca de actualizaciones de archivos externos

Tags: php, html, css

¡Hola de nuevo! Bueno, no se me ocurrio un mejor titulo, comenzando con mi pregunta, basicamente, en php para poder actualizar los estilos css, las imagenes y demas de una pagina php, debo actualizar el link que redirige hacia ellos, algo como esto:

```
"<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css?1.0">"
```

Como ven, luego del nombre del archivo, pongo un "?" y una version.
Mi pregunta es si hay alguna manera mas efectiva y rapida de hacerlo, ya que cada vez que actualizo mis estilos css, debo actualizar tambien el archivo php con el link.

Pense en primero crear la pagina en html, en cuanto tenga los estilos y todo listo, la paso a php, pero ya es tarde, porque cuando me di cuenta que habia que actualizarlo, ya habia creado todos los archivos de mi pagina. ¿No hay alguna manera de hacer que se actualice automaticamente o algo parecido? ¡Gracias por la ayuda que puedan brindarme!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay una manera dinamica de generar la URL de manera que solo si cambia la fecha de modificacion del archivo (suponiendo que se aplica en un archivo .php)

Con codigo PHP ***inline***

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css?<?=filemtime("styles.css")?>" >
```

O usando una cadena de texto:

```
<?php
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css?'.filemtime("styles.css").'" >'
```

Si las paginas son HTML y por tanto no puedes incrustar codigo PHP dinamicamente, sera dificil hacer algo que se ajuste dinamicamente (podria ser un reemplazo general en archivos). Si tienes la posibilidad de cambiar las paginas a PHP solo se necesitaria el ajuste anterior.

Puedes usar un codigo Javascript para cargar el .css de forma dinamica, pero esto implica modificar cada archivo .html para incluir este codigo (aunque esto se haria solo una vez):

```
function loadCSS(url){
    // Create link 
    var link = document.createElement('link'); 
    link.rel = 'stylesheet';  
    link.type = 'text/css'; 
    link.href = url+'?'+Math.round();  
    // Append link 
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD')[0];  
    head.appendChild(link);  
}
```

Y llamarlo como

```
<script>loadCss('style.css');</script>
```

Comment: Te amo... Simplemente te amo, no te das una idea de lo que me rompi la cabeza y el tiempo que perdi con este problema, muchisimas, pero MUCHISIMAS gracias

Comment: AY DIOS NO TE DAS UNA IDEA DE LO FELIZ QUE ESTOY, te mereces todo lo bueno que te pase jajasjas